# How do I compare if the words of a string are in another in the same order, independent of grammatical number?

Tags: perl

I need to compare two sentences and return true if all the words of `$string1` are in `$string2` in same order. The word match has to account for singular/plural and omit the articles "a, an, the" from the match. What is the best approach to find the singular/plural comparison of words?

```
$string1 = " i have a sunglass";
$string2 = " i have sunglasses in my purse";
$string3 = " the sunglass i have is blue in color";
```

`$string1`, when compared to `$string2` should return true but with `$string3` it should result false.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? Please share any code or algorithms you've come up with.

You can split a string into an array of words in Perl using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

For stemming, have a look at [Lingua::Stem](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua%3a%3aStem) on CPAN.